# Can fertiliser be spread at the same time as seed for a new lawn?

Tags: grass

I'm about to seed a new lawn and was recommended a fertilizer for new lawn. Is it reasonable to simply pre-mix the required proportions of seed and fertiliser and spread this all in one go, or does fertiliser need to wait a while after sowing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, so long as the fertilizer is designed for this purpose.

A "general purpose" lawn fertilizer will probably "burn" the seedlings as they germinate, which is obviously not a good idea.

Note that any "feed and weed" fertilizer mix should *never* be applied to a newly seeded lawn until the grass has become established - typically a minimum of 4 weeks after germination in complete (i.e. not "4 weeks after you see the first blade of grass appear").